# C++ linked list data structure program doesn't seem to work, unknown error

Tags: c++

Here's the code

Data.h:

```
#pragma once

    class List
    {
    private:
        typedef struct node{
            int data; 
            node* next; 
        }* nodePtr;
    
    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr; 
    nodePtr temp; 
    
   
    public: 
        List();
        void AddNode(int addData);
        void DeleteNode(int delData);
        void PrintList();
};
```

Implementation.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Data.h"
using namespace std;

List::List(){

    head = NULL;    
    curr = NULL;    
    temp = NULL;
}
void List::AddNode(int addData){    
    nodePtr n = new node;    
    n->next = NULL;    
    n->next = addData;
    
    if(head !=NULL){
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next !=NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
    }
    else
    {
        head = n;
    }   
}
void List::DeleteNode (int delData){    
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;    
    temp = head;    
    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL && curr->data != delData){
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL){
        cout << delData << "is not on the list\n";
        delete delPtr;
    }
    else{
        delPtr = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        temp->next = curr;
        if (delPtr == head){
            head = head->next;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        delete delPtr;
        cout << "The value" <<delData <<"was deleted\n";
    }
}
void List::PrintList(){    
    curr = head;

    while (curr !=NULL){    
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Data.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    List Paul;
    
    Paul.AddNode(3);
    Paul.AddNode(5);
    Paul.AddNode(7);
    Paul.PrintList();
    
    Paul.DeleteNode(5);
    Paul.PrintList();
}
```

Here's the error whenever I compile and run it:

/tmp/ccbTqkUo.o: In function `main': Main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to` List::List()'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `List::AddNode(int)' Main.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to` List::AddNode(int)'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `List::AddNode(int)' Main.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to` List::PrintList()'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `List::DeleteNode(int)' Main.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to` List::PrintList()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Try to add: " #include<Implementation.cpp>  " at the end of your Data.h file

Comment: Still an error

Data.h:21:9: fatal error: Implementation.cpp: No such file or directory
 #include<Implementation.cpp>

Comment: how are you compiling/linking your code?

Comment: Typo line 14 of `implementation.cpp` where `// n->next = addData;` should be `n->data = addData;` (you compiler should have warned about invalid conversion from `int`). After fixing, your output looks as you expect, node with value `5` is deleted. Compile as, e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c++14 -Ofast main.cpp implementation.cpp -o main`

Comment: @VoQuocThang You *do not* include `.cpp` code. You need to link. That's, fortunately, the wrong way to do it anyway.

Comment: You need to compile *both* `.cpp` files into their respective `.o` versions (or whatever form your compiler emits) and then link those two together into the final executable. This usually requires either a script, or a build tool like `make` or CMake or an IDE.